# Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c, pointers, integer

I'm a beginner in c++ programming and I have this activity in school. I keep getting [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] in line 15. How do you solve this? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int pass[5];
int x;
main()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter pin code: ";
    for(x=0;x<=4;x++)
    {
        pass[x]=getch();
        putch('#');
    }   
    if(pass==86222)
        cout<<"\nW E L C O M E!";
    else
        cout<<"\nIncorrect Pin Code";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You are doing things in a very strange way. If you wanna compare `int`s. Take and `int`, read it and compare, Why is the `array` needed?

Comment: Posted a simple way to do what you are trying.

Comment: @Haris We need to hide the pin code with # or something like entering a password.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing things in a very strange way. If you wanna compare `int`s. Take and `int`, read it and compare, Why is the `array` needed?

The best and simple way to do this is to use only `int`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int pass;
    cout<<"\nEnter pin code: ";
    cin>>pass;

    if(pass==86222)
        cout<<"\nW E L C O M E!";
    else
        cout<<"\nIncorrect Pin Code";
    getch();
}
```

---

If you want to do it the way you want, then use `strcmp()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char pass[5];
int x;
main()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter pin code: ";
    for(x=0;x<=4;x++)
    {
        pass[x]=getch();
        putch('#');
    }   
    if(!strcmp(pass, "86222"))
        cout<<"\nW E L C O M E!";
    else
        cout<<"\nIncorrect Pin Code";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: We need to hide the pin code with # or something like entering a password. @Haris

Comment: It says [Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

Comment: @hdlsswrrr, Sorry, mistake.. it should be `char pass[5]`

Answer (score 0):

You are reading characters and comparing them as ints. That won't work....

The following first places the charactes into an array of characters, then converts that aray to an int and compares the int:

```
char passch[6];
int pass, x;
main()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter pin code: ";
    for(x=0;x<=4;x++)
    {
        passch[x]=getch();
        putch('#');
    } 
    passch[5]= '\0';
    pass= atoi(passch);
    if(pass==86222)
        cout<<"\nW E L C O M E!";
    else
        cout<<"\nIncorrect Pin Code";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: This seems more like a comment to me.

Comment: What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

pass is an array (which is implemented in c++ as a pointer) and 86222 is an integer.  you cannot compare those.

As @haris said in their comment, you really just want to store the input as an integer.  you do this with `std::cin >> pass`.  then you can compare `pass` with your stored value.